# How can I protect my script from being "free"?

Tags: php, web-applications

I want to divide my web application into two parts. 
One part is free, like a demo for people to use.
The other part is not; a extension that is paid for but requires authorization and a license to use.

My idea is to sell the extension without having it being compromised. Once the extension is sold, the buyer can't upload it to some other site and make it "free" for other people to use. Thus the extension would check a database from another domain to authorize the use of its script.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Anything you give to users for them to run on their own server can be modified to circumvent security measures. The only safe way is to not let them have the source code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give the free script away for users to run on their own site.  Run the licensed non-free script only on your server and hook them together using an API over HTTP.

Comment: Of course, this option means that any calculations would have to be done on your server, and your customers won't be able to use their software when they're not connected to the Internet...

Comment: The requirement that the script check authorization from another domain basically means that the script can't be used offline anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use a professional solution like [Zend Guard](http://www.zend.com/products/guard/).